# Time - Limited Video Recording : Show max time in Camera App

Tags: android, video, android-intent, camera

I am working on an application in which video capturing is required.

Everything is working fine like:

1. open camera for Video recording.
2. video is being recorded for 20 seconds.
3. video preview and everything.

Issue :

the Issue is when i start video recording then camera app stops the video recording after 20 seconds(which is correct), but user get notified only after 20 seconds that "maximum recoding time reached".

and while recording it is showing :

(recoded time)/(total time which can be recorded).

what i want:

i want to show user (remaining Time)/(20 seconds).

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_VIDEO_RECORDING_LIMIT = 20;
    private static final int VIDEO_RECORDING_QUALITY = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dispatchTakeVideoIntent();
    }

    private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {

        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, MAXIMUM_VIDEO_RECORDING_LIMIT);
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, VIDEO_RECORDING_QUALITY);

        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri file = data.getData();

        }
    }
}
```

How it can be implemented, please help.

Comment: You want to show remaining time as per your sd card memory or like snapchat to allow user to record only 10 or 20 seconds video ?

Comment: @Naitik: i want to allow user to only recod 20 seconds video.